# Not running after enter input

Tags: python

I work in sublime text 3 and I know my code is very simply.when I enter input and press enter key in keyboard nothing else happen and ready still to get input from keyboard.what's wrong?thanks for any help.

```
def is_even(k):  
    if k % 2 == 0:  
        print ("%s is even." % (k))  
        return True  
print (is_even(int(input("Please enter number: "))))
```

Comment: Also, how are you running it? When using the Sublime Text 3 Build option, the console doesn't actually connect stdin to the process, so pressing enter doesn't send anything to the process. Run this in your terminal instead.

Comment: What do you mean as you said running in terminal instead?

Comment: On Windows: open a command prompt and run your script there. On Linux or Mac, open a terminal and run your script there. The Sublime Text console can't be used.

Comment: my god running in command prompt is a long way!!Now I do it and thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this.

```
def is_even(k):  
    if k % 2 == 0:   
        return True  
number = int(input("Please enter number: ")) 
if is_even(number)==True:
    print ("%s is even." % (number))
else:
    print ("%s is  not even." % (number))
```

Comment: Edited because I had True in the If statement by mistake

Comment: You don't need the `True` in the condition at at all

Comment: You don't need it with or without quotes. `if x == True` is exactly the same as `if x`.

Comment: just my personal preference, always done it this way

Comment: [Worth a read](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: Pair of them are ture but if x is better certainly.

Comment: i just prefer to make my code more readable for the less experienced

Comment: Thanks in any way and your code is more useful than my code.my main question is something that related to sublime.after enter number, sublime doesn't run code because still is in input mode and if you see comments I have to run in cmd.